# Validation doesn't work?

Tags: backbone.js

I have some code:

```
       var Person = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Jeremy'});

        Person.validate = function(attrs) {
            if (!attrs.name) {
                return 'I need your name';
            }
        };

        Person.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
          alert(model.get("title") + " " + error);
        });


        Person.set({name: 'Samuel'});
        console.log(Person.get('name'));
        // 'Samuel'

        Person.unset('name', {validate: true});
        console.log(Person.get('name'));//Why can i print name here if it unsetted?
```

When i type unset method i see an error alert. It's correct. But why can i print in console the name if it was unsetted?

Answer (score 0):

The `name` is still there because the validation failure stopped the `unset` from doing anything.

The [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) isn't very explicit about how validation works with `set` and `unset` but it is quite explicit with `save`:

> **validate** `model.validate(attributes, options)`
>
> [...] If **validate** returns an error, `save` will not continue, and the model attributes will not be modified on the server.

So it is reasonable to think that validation errors will prevent the current operation (`set`, `unset`, `save`, ...) from changing anything.

You can see how it works by examining the Backbone source code. First, you need to know that [`unset`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L378) is just a `set` call in disguise:

```
unset: function(attr, options) {
  return this.set(attr, void 0, _.extend({}, options, {unset: true}));
}
```

So we look at [`set`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L308):

```
set: function(key, val, options) {
  // A bunch of boring bookkeeping stuff...

  // Run validation.
  if (!this._validate(attrs, options)) return false;

  // The stuff that changes attributes and triggers events.
}
```

The validations happen as soon as `set` knows what it is working with and `set` returns without changing anything if the validations fail.

The Backbone documentation leaves a lot of important things out so you need to be passingly familiar with the Backbone source if you're going to use Backbone. The source is fairly straight forward, don't be afraid to jump into it to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: To not trigger events you can use the silent:true option. I believe there might be some issue upstream in your code. Anyways, do the following - it should work. ( in my tests, it did ).

```
Person.unset('name',{validate: true,silent:true})
```

p.s.: Mu ( below ) gives great information.